# Python 3.9 - How to print and format a .txt file?

Tags: python, format, text-files, python-3.9

How would I define a function so that the text file may printed out in a particular way without changing the contents of the file? Or perhaps what would be a more efficient method of going about this?

**Text file:**

```
menu.txt
Cheese Burger, 5.00
Chicken Burger, 4.50
Fries, 2.00
Onion Rings, 2.50
Drinks, 1.50
```

**Desired output:**

```
1.  Cheese Burger           5.00
2.  Chicken Burger          4.50        
3.  Fries                   2.00
4.  Onion Rings             2.50
5.  Drinks                  1.50
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to get that serial numbers starting from `1`.

To print the output the way you mentioned you need to use `String formatting` - [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

I have used `{item:25}` - This will make the item to be of width 25. You can put whatever number you wish to get desired space.

From the Docs:

> Passing an integer after the ':' will cause that field to be a minimum number of characters wide. This is useful for making columns line up.

```
with open('menu.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i,v in enumerate(lines,1):
        item, price = v.strip('\n').split(',')
        print(f'{i}. {item:25}{price}')
```

```
Output

1. Cheese Burger             5.00
2. Chicken Burger            4.50
3. Fries                     2.00
4. Onion Rings               2.50
5. Drinks                    1.50
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open file in read ("r") mode to use it without changing. ./Menu.txt means the file and .py file are in the same folder. You can write exact path instead of "./Menu.txt".

```
file = open("./Menu.txt", "r")

lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
num_of_line = 1

for line in lines:
    res = line.split(", ")
    print(num_of_line, end=". ")
    print(f"{res[0] : <20}{res[1] : ^5}")
    num_of_line += 1
```

Comment: The output is a little different than what I expected, but if I add end="" to the print statement I basically get what I want. Thank you.